# ¿Como obtener el último valor de lista que no séa cero?

Tags: python, array, lista, odoo, openerp

Estoy haciendo una función en Odoo 15, la cual toma los registros de una tabla llamada *product_supplierinfo*, toma el valor del costo y lo asigna a un campo llamado *costo_anterior*, sin embargo, a veces el último registro es cero, por lo que la función debería tomar el valor anterior a ese, es decir, el penúltimo & así sucesivamente hasta que encuentre un valor diferente de cero.

Tengo ya una función que lo hace, sin embargo, no creo que sea tan funcional cuando existan más de 5 o 6 registros.

A continuación dejo la función que comento anteriormente:

```
@api.depends('seller_ids')
def _previous_cost(self):
    self.ensure_one()

    _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    if self.default_code or self.default_code != '':
        product_search = self.env['product.product'].search([('default_code', '=', self.default_code)], limit=1)
        all_seller_ids = product_search.seller_ids.ids
        _logger.info('seller_ids: %s', all_seller_ids)

        if len(all_seller_ids) < 1:
            self.previous_cost = 0.0
        else:
            if all_seller_ids:
                id_ultimo_costo = all_seller_ids[-1]
                supplier = self.env['product.supplierinfo'].search([('id', '=', id_ultimo_costo)])
                self.previous_cost = supplier.price
                _logger.info('Costo anterior: %s', self.previous_cost)

                if len(all_seller_ids) > 1:
                    if self.previous_cost == 0.0:
                        id_ultimo_costo = all_seller_ids[-2]
                        supplier = self.env['product.supplierinfo'].search([('id', '=', id_ultimo_costo)])
                        self.previous_cost = supplier.price
                        _logger.info('Costo anterior: %s', self.previous_cost)
                        if len(all_seller_ids) > 2:
                            if self.previous_cost == 0.0:
                                id_ultimo_costo = all_seller_ids[-3]
                                supplier = self.env['product.supplierinfo'].search([('id', '=', id_ultimo_costo)])
                                self.previous_cost = supplier.price
                                _logger.info('Costo anterior: %s', self.previous_cost)
                            else:
                                _logger.info('Registro [-3] no es igual a 0.0')
                        else:
                            self.previous_cost = 0.0
                    else:
                        self.previous_cost = 0.0
                else:
                    self.previous_cost = 0.0
            else:
                self.previous_cost = 0.0
```

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No conozco mucho de `odoo`, pero sería más fácil hacer la consulta adecuada.

Es decir, tienes algo como esto

```
--------------------------
|     id     |   price   |
--------------------------
|     10     |    100    |
|     15     |     0     |
|     20     |    400    |
|     22     |     0     |
|     25     |     0     |
--------------------------
```

A simple vista podemos ver que lo que necesitas es únicamente el valor `400`, ya que de atrás hacia adelante.

Por lo que tenemos que hacer simplemente

```
SELECT * 
FROM product_supplierinfo
WHERE 
    id IN (10, 15, 20, 25) AND price <> 0
ORDER BY id desc
LIMIT 1
```

Si haces esta consulta a tu `db` debería traerte un único registro que sería

```
|     20     |    400    |
```

Ahora en `Oddo` tendrías que hacer simplemente algo como

```
if all_seller_ids:
    supplier = self.env['product.supplierinfo'].search([('id', 'in', all_seller_ids), ('price', '!=', 0)])
    self.previous_cost = supplier.price if supplier else 0.0
    _logger.info('Costo anterior: %s', self.previous_cost)
```

**NOTA**
Como te mencione, no conozco mucho de `odoo` pero en todo caso solo sería ajustar

```
 supplier = self.env['product.supplierinfo'].search([('id', 'in', all_seller_ids), ('price', '!=', 0)])
```

A la forma correcta si es que esto te trae un arreglo `supplier[0]`o si falla en algo adaptarlo a la consulta a anterior.

Comment: Funcionó correctamente aunque de supplier todavía tomé el valor de `supplier.price` para que la condición **else** funcionara correctamente. Muchas gracias!!!